# In ajax requests what does a preceeding `/` in the url specify?

Tags: javascript

I noticed it works both ways, but which way are you suppose to do it?

**Particular Case**

```
$FOO.ajax({
    type:       'get',
    url:        src, // the src works with both a preceding / and with out
    // ...
```

Comment: `/` is needed to target a root.

Comment: Use whatever suits you best. Neither is always better.

Comment: If it works both ways, it's because the file that the script is running from is in the root, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Wait.. why is this question being closed? It's perfectly legitimate and well-formed. What's going on with SO as of late?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/path/file.ext` is relative to the domain, whereas `path/file.ext` is relative to the current folder.

If you're in the top-level folder of the domain, then there's no difference, but for consistency it's generally safer to include the `/` and have your paths be relative to the root.

Comment: ...not in my case....my application is reflective, it finds out where it is and updates paths on both the server and the client.

Comment: @pure_code what? The details in this answer are *always* the case. If you have some mitigating or interfering factor, then only you know about that.... and this question is pointless because only you can answer.

Comment: @pure_code then you could use absolute URLs (`http://example.com/path.file.ext`) as well.

Comment: FWIW, I never hard code this stuff. `/path/to/resource` breaks when you've installed something in a subdirectory (maybe for demo purposes or testing, whatever). Use a dynamic absolute base, then append it. Or use a function.